# Concatenating data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have the following data in my database:

```
initial   |    word
---------------------------
   E      |    Example1
   E      |    Example2
   N      |    Nextexample1
```

**The desired output:**

```
E : Example1, Example2
N : Nextexample1
```

So for each initial, it should display all the words starting with that initial.

**Output at this moment:**

```
E : Example1
E : Example2
N : Nextexample1
```

**My code at this moment:**

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...');           
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT initial, word FROM `exampletable` ORDER by initial ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmtrecords = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

    foreach($stmtrecords as $result)
    {
?>

<?php echo $result['initial'];?> : <?php echo $result['word'];?>
```

**The question:**

I completely understand why I'm getting the wrong output but don't know how to solve it. I guess I need something like a foreach loop within a foreach loop to get the right output, but how to link the words to the correct initial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a single `SQL` query.

```
SELECT `initial`, GROUP_CONCAT(`word` SEPARATOR ', ') as `output` 
    FROM `table` GROUP BY `initial` ORDER BY `initial` ASC
```

In this query you are asking `MySQL` to group the records by `initial` and you use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to aggregate each grouping into a single single row.

**Using example data**

```
initial | word
--------+--------------
E       | Example1
E       | Example2
Z       | Zebra
N       | NextExample
O       | OtherExample
O       | OtherExample2
```

**Would return:**

```
initial | output
--------+--------------
E       | Example1, Example2
N       | NextExample
O       | OtherExample, OtherExample2
Z       | Zebra
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Just one more question: if I would decide to put each word matching the initial into a separate div, any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Stan Obviously through a loop, but you might want to ask a second question. ;-)